# Execute code only if parent transaction completes

Tags: .net, transactions, system.transactions

The code below will output:

```
Event published
Command executed
```

Using System.Transactions how can I have the EventPublisher enlist in a parent transaction such that it only executes if the CommandHandler completes. The output would therefore be:

```
Command executed
Event published
```

Code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            var handler = new CommandHandler();
            handler.Execute();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class CommandHandler
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            var foo = new Foo();
            foo.DoSomething();

            Console.WriteLine("Command executed");
        }
    }

    public class EventPublisher
    {
        public void PublishEvent()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event published");
        }
    }
public class Foo
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        new EventPublisher().PublishEvent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually to enlist in the transaction by implementing [IEnlistmentNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is the asynchronous code execution beside the transactions that spans all the code